# How to proof the Casimir element is in the Center of U(g)

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I have this definition of the Casimir element from Knapp p.294 
$$
\Omega= {\sum}  B\left(X_{i},X_{j}\right)\widetilde{X}_{i}\widetilde{X}_{j}.
$$
The prrof that Knapp does for the Casimir element being in the center of U(g) is a little bit cumbersome using a previus lemma etc. All other books I know do a simple proof but based on another definition. Does anybody see a short way with few lines to proof the centrality of the Casimir element starting from this definition? By the way... does anybody know why Knapp use this definition of the Casimir element?
Thanks in advance

Comment: In Knapp's book "Lie groups beyond an introduction" he defines this indeed like this, but the proof (Proposition 5.24, page 239) is not cumbersome at all. On the contrary, it is the usual proof, just with $B(X_i,X_j)$.

Comment: But it relies on Lemma 5.22

Comment: Which indeed is not difficult it's just that I liked more something like Hall p. 270. I'm doing some notes that should not more that 30p. and I'm trying to be more synthetic as possible...

Comment: It relies on Proposition $5.22$, which is a triviality about the center of $U(\mathfrak{g})$. The proof of it is just $5$ lines.

Comment: I know, I know is not a problem of how hard it is... Do you also have an idea of why does Knapp use this definition of the Casimir element?

Comment: I have written down a proof [here](http://homepage.univie.ac.at/Dietrich.Burde/papers/burde_28_lie_algebra_course.pdf), page 44 and 45. But it uses the other definition, I know....Why does Knapp use this definition? I think, he wanted to be a bit more general. But I am not sure, of course.

Comment: I think I can work out from your proof what I need. Thank you